# Java: accessing bean-type methods of an Object through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans

Is this the appropriate way to access bean properties of an Object without knowing/caring about its exact type? (Or is there a built-in method that does this already?) Is there an appropriate exception to throw when a property does not exist or is not available?

```
static private Object getBeanPropertyValue(Object bean, String propertyName) {
    // access a no-arg method through reflection
    // following bean naming conventions
    try {
        Method m = bean.getClass().getMethod(
                "get"
                +propertyName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
                +propertyName.substring(1)
                , null);
        return m.invoke(bean);
    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        // (gulp) -- swallow exception and move on
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        // (gulp) -- swallow exception and move on
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // (gulp) -- swallow exception and move on
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // (gulp) -- swallow exception and move on
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // (gulp) -- swallow exception and move on
    }
    return null; // it would be better to throw an exception, wouldn't it?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use Commons BeanUtils, you can get there with jre classes

java.beans.Introspector

```
BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean.getClass());
PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
for(PropertyDescriptor pd : descriptors)
{
    if(pd.getName().equals(propertyName)
    {
        return pd.getReadMethod().invoke(bean, (Object[])null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A wrapper such as Commons BeanUtils would be nice if you don't mind the third party dependency.  Otherwise, I'd suggest looking at the [Java BeanInfo](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) class to provide what you need.

IllegalArgumentException might be a reasonable thing to throw, but really, almost anything would be better than just swallowing the exception.

Comment: Certainly using java.beans makes more sense than using reflection directly if you are trying to obey the beans standard. As for exceptions, swallowing is a sure sign of doing something wrong (in the case of using reflection the thing being done wrong is probably using reflection). Here, even unchecked exceptions from teh method are swallowed. I think it goes without saying that there is no security here.

Answer (score 2):

Umm... this wouldn't handle booleans (e.g. 'isActive()`) or nested / indexed properties.

I suggest you take a look at [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) instead of trying to write this yourself.

[BeanUtils.getProperty()](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#getProperty) does what you want. Doesn't swallow exceptions either :-)